# I am having trouble with compatibility between NSArray and NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am having trouble with compatibility between NSArray and NSMutableArray?
--> Incompatible Objective-C types assigning "struct NSArray *", expected "struct NSMutableArray"

```
NSMutableArray *nsmarrRow;

NSString *nsstrFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: nsstrFilename ofType: nsstrExtension];
NSString *nsstrFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: nsstrFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];

//break up file into rows
nsmarrRow = [nsstrFileContents componentsSeparatedByString: nsstrRowParse];//<--Incompatible Objective-C types assigning "struct NSArray *", expected "struct NSMutableArray"
```

I have tried making the "NSString declaration"  to  "NSMutableString"... made more problems.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get a mutable array by doing

```
nsmarrRow = [nsstrFileContents componentsSeparatedByString: nsstrRowParse];
```

You will need to,

```
nsmarrRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[nsstrFileContents componentsSeparatedByString: nsstrRowParse]];
```

Changing `NSString` to `NSMutableString` won't give you an `NSMutableArray` object. You will get an `NSArray` object just as in case of `NSString`. You will have to use that to get an `NSMutableArray` using the above method.

Answer (score 2):

The `componentsSeparatedByString` method returns an NSArray. Try the following:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[nsstrFileContents componentsSeparatedByString: nsstrRowParse]];
```